# Set content of image/file (Not just URL) by getting it from DB to input type file

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am uploading a file to DB using `ng-file-upload` in `base64` format, It works fine. Now I would like to set it to `<input type="file" name="fileDB" />`.
What are the possible ways to do it? It is not just showing the image on page, I would like to set to input element as it should look like it was selected by browsing.